# ASP.NET Core Web API - Problem with fucntion MapControllerRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have basically defined 2 routes to different controllers:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "projects",
    pattern: "projects",
    defaults: new { controller = "Projects", action = "get" }
);

endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "models",
    pattern: "models",
    defaults: new { controller = "Models", action = "get" }
);
```

The two get methods of the controllers:

```
public class ProjectsController : ODataController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        List<Project> AllProjects = _dbContext.Projects.ToList();
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AllProjects);
    }
}

public class ModelsController : ODataController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        var AllModels = _dbContext.Models.ToList();
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AllModels);
    }
}
```

Now the get method of the projects controller is getting called correctly when visiting https://localhost:44357/projects. When I do the same just with models so https://localhost:44357/models then I get a 404 returned. Every other routing that I have for the ModelsController is working perfectly fine besides this one.
**Why does that happen and what do I need to do to make this work?**

**EDIT:**

Here is the startup Code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                builder =>
                                {
                                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
                                });
        });

        services.AddCors();
        services.AddControllers().AddOData(opt => opt.Count()
                                                .Filter()
                                                .OrderBy()
                                                .Expand()
                                                .Select()
                                                .AddRouteComponents("v", GetEdmModel()));

        services.AddDbContext<WebDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebDbContext"))
            //.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        );

           

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "test",
                pattern: "test/data",
                defaults: new { controller = "Models", action = "addsampledata" }
            );

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "projects",
                pattern: "projects/create",
                defaults: new { controller = "Projects", action = "createproject" }
            );

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "projects",
                pattern: "projects",
                defaults: new { controller = "Projects", action = "getprojects" }
            );

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "models",
                pattern: "models",
                defaults: new { controller = "Models", action = "getmodels" }
            );

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "models",
                pattern: "models/create",
                defaults: new { controller = "Models", action = "createmodel" }
            );

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "models",
                pattern: "models/retrieve/{model}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Models", action = "retrievemodels" }
            );

        });
    }

    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Model>("Models").EntityType.HasMany(m => m.SubModels);
        builder.EntitySet<Property>("Propterties");//.EntityType.HasKey(prop => prop.ParentModel);
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

The Models Controller:

```
public class ModelsController : ODataController
{
    private WebDbContext _dbContext;
    public ModelsController(WebDbContext context)
    {
        _dbContext = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string GetModels()
    {
        var AllModels = _dbContext.Models.ToList();

        foreach(Model model in AllModels)
        {
            LoadRecursively(model);
        }
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AllModels);
    }

    public void AddSampleData()
    {

        List<Property> properties = new List<Property>();

        Project TestProject = new Project
        {
            Name = "TestProject",
            //Models = AllModels
        };

        Model Salami = new Model
        {
            Name = "Salami",
            SubModels = null,
            Properties = properties,
            ProjectId = TestProject
        };

        Property SalamiMeat = new Property
        {
            Name = "Salami Meat",
        };

        properties.Add(SalamiMeat);

        List<Model> CheeseModels = new List<Model>();

        Model Cheese = new Model
        {
            Name = "Cheese",
            SubModels = CheeseModels,
            ProjectId = TestProject
        };

        Model CheeseShape = new Model
        {
            Name = "CheeseShape",
            SubModels = null,
            ProjectId = TestProject
        };

        Model CheeseOrigin = new Model
        {
            Name = "CheeseOrigin",
            SubModels = null,
            ProjectId = TestProject
        };

        CheeseModels.Add(CheeseShape);
        CheeseModels.Add(CheeseOrigin);

        List<Model> Ingredients = new List<Model>();
        Ingredients.Add(Salami);
        Ingredients.Add(Cheese);

        Model Pizza = new Model
        {
            Name = "pizza",
            SubModels = Ingredients,
            ProjectId = TestProject
        };

        List<Model> AllModels = new List<Model>();
        AllModels.Add(Pizza);
        AllModels.Add(Salami);
        AllModels.Add(Cheese);
        AllModels.Add(CheeseOrigin);
        AllModels.Add(CheeseShape);

        //Pizza.ParentModel = null;
        //Salami.ParentModel = Pizza;
        //Cheese.ParentModel = Pizza;
        //CheeseOrigin.ParentModel = Cheese;
        //CheeseShape.ParentModel = Cheese;

        _dbContext.Add(TestProject);
        _dbContext.Add(Pizza);
        _dbContext.Add(Salami);
        _dbContext.Add(SalamiMeat);
        _dbContext.Add(Cheese);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public string RetrieveModels(string model)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            Error = (sender, args) =>
            {
                args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
            },

        };

        //var project = _dbContext.Projects.Include(p => p.Models).ThenInclude(m => m.Properties);
        //return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(project, settings);

        var pizza = _dbContext.Models.Where(m => m.Name.Equals(model)).First();
        LoadRecursively(pizza);

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pizza, settings);
    }
        
    public string CreateModel([FromBody] CreateModelData modelData)
    {
        var ToAddProject = _dbContext.Projects.Where(p => p.ID == modelData.ProjectId).First();

        Model NewModel = new Model()
        {
            Name = modelData.ModelName,
            ProjectId = ToAddProject
        };

        //if (ToAddProject != null)
        //{
        //    ToAddProject.Models.Add(NewModel);
        //}
        _dbContext.Models.Add(NewModel);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NewModel);
    }

    public void LoadRecursively(Model model)
    {
        _dbContext.Entry(model).Collection(m => m.SubModels).Load();
        _dbContext.Entry(model).Collection(m => m.Properties).Load();
        _dbContext.Entry(model).Reference(m => m.ProjectId).Load();
        //_dbContext.Entry(model).Reference(m => m.ParentModel).Load();
            
        foreach (var SubModel in model.SubModels)
        {
            _dbContext.Entry(SubModel).Collection(m => m.Properties).Load();
            _dbContext.Entry(model).Reference(m => m.ProjectId).Load();
            //_dbContext.Entry(model).Reference(m => m.ParentModel).Load();
            LoadRecursively(SubModel);
        }                      
    }

    public void BulkInsert()
    {
        List<Model> insertList = new List<Model>();
        const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {

            string randomString = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 5)
                .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());

            Model temp = new Model
            {
                Name = randomString,
            };
            insertList.Add(temp);
        }

        _dbContext.Models.BulkInsert(insertList);
    }

    //[HttpGet]
    //[EnableQuery]
    //public IEnumerable<Model> Get()
    //{
    //    return _dbContext.Models;//.Where(m => m.ID == key).Include(m => m.SubModel);
    //}

}
```

Comment: Hi @Florent, have you solved the problem? Based on your code, I create a sample and your code works well on my side, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZTGq.gif) (refresh the page via Ctrl+F5). You could try to clear the browser data (such as cache, cookie), then check whether the page works or not? If still not working the issue might relate other setting, you could post the whole code about the ModelsController and the router configuration. Or you can delete the Models controller first and re-add it.

Comment: Hi @ZhiLv, weirdly enough I suppose the you cant name the actions the same. When I changed the name of the action get of the ModelsController to the name get2 then it worked once. Now I dont want to name it get2 for obvious reasons so I changed the name to something more describing like getmodels. Then it didnt work again. Now I can only name it get2 otherwise it doesnt  work. I cleared the browser data etc. but that didnt solve it. I post some more code

Comment: @ZhiLv Found the error: I commented out the OData stuff then it worked. If you name a method speicifcally Get + something then OData will take it as the get method. That was the problem I guess. Thank you very much